# ExtJS 4 Use same listener for several selectors

Tags: extjs

I use same listener for several selectors in my controller:

```
init: function() {
    this.control( {
        'form combo[name="name1"]': {
            afterrender: this.doSmt
        },
        'form combo[name="name2"]': {
            afterrender: this.doSmt
        },
        'form combo[name="name3"]': {
            afterrender: this.doSmt
        }
    } );
}
```

Is it possible to simplify this code and list all selectors at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
'form combo[name=name1], form combo[name=name2], form combo[name=name3]': {
    afterrender: this.doSmt
}
```

it should work.

edit:

don't use `"` in the property matches!